# Roc_auc percentage calculation giving nan

Tags: python, dataframe, scikit-learn, auc

I am trying to calculate the ROC score for my data but it is resulting in nan.

The code:

```
scoring = 'roc_auc'
kfold= KFold(n_splits=10, random_state=42, shuffle=True)
model = LinearDiscriminantAnalysis()
results = cross_val_score(model, df_n, y, cv=kfold, scoring=scoring)
print("AUC: %.3f (%.3f)" % (results.mean(), results.std()))
```

df_n is an array from the normalised values, I also tried it just with the X data value from the dataset.
y is an array of binary values.

df_n shape: (150, 4)
y shape: (150,)

I am stumped, it should work!

Comment: You should probably not be one-hot encoding the target.

Comment: yes, thats what I was thinking too... I think I will just skip the roc_score here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `roc_auc_score` expects the probabilities and not the predictions in the case of multi-class classification. However, with that code the score is getting the output of `predict` instead.

Use a new scorer:

```
from sklearn.metrics import roc_auc_score, make_scorer

multi_roc_scorer = make_scorer(lambda y_in, y_p_in: roc_auc_score(y_in, y_p_in, multi_class='ovr'), needs_proba=True)
scores = cross_validate(model, X_s, y_s, scoring=multi_roc_scorer, cv=cv, error_score="raise")
```

Comment: Thank you this worked well on its own, but I cannot use it with the data. Instead I am calculating it on its own and still having an error.